# My companies Outlook blocks my emails but not others

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I have a Gmail account and my company has an @companyname outlook email.  No emails I send them get delivered, but other Gmail accounts can send emails to them, so it has to be something with my Gmail.

I do not get a bounce back or failed to deliver email. It is not in their spam or trash either. Me and a coworker sat down for a few minutes trying to figure it out yesterday before we gave up.

I have talked to our IT guy, but he isn't sure what is happening. There is no block on my email and this is the first time he has seen this issue. Other coworkers emails that are Gmail get delivered fine.

He is going to dig deeper, but I figured asking the community would be a great way to help get a direction to look at.

Comment: You have not provided us anything to go on, and this is likely not something we can help with.  You need to engage with your companies IT department.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What does that mean?  Does it go into spam, does it bounce... details details details...

Comment: Have you asked your company's IT staff? Perhaps others have had that issue.

Comment: For corporate IT issues you should speak to your IT department.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much information to go on.  However, I have a very strong feeling the following is correct.

If you had received a bounce back email saying your sent email was rejected, you would have mentioned it.  Since you didn't mention it, I am assuming you didn't receive one.  This strongly suggests that your email *is* being delivered.  Since they aren't seeing it, this is likely due to it being sent to the spam folder or being filtered in some other way by the recipient.  You would need to talk to your company's IT provider to check the  email logs to see what is actually happening to it.